# How do I deploy an ASP .Net website built with VB which is hosted on a server to a webpart in Sharepoint 2013 with SharePoint 2013 authentication?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have this website I wanna deploy it in a web part but i want to authenticate it also from SharePoint 2013.
I don't want user to log in SharePoint then again in my website inside the web part.

Please and thank you !